# Cannot install the silverstripe-fluent module using composer

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe-4

There is some issue I am unable to install the Silverstripe fluent module using composer ? I get the following error when I run:

```
composer require tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent:^4
```

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent 4 exists as tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent[3.1.0, 3.1.0.x-dev, 3.1.1, 3.1.x-dev,
>   3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.x-dev, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.6.0, 3.7.0, 3.7.x-dev, 3.8.0, 3.8.1, 3.8.x-dev, 3.x-dev, 3.9.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha1, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.0.0-beta2, 4.0.0-beta3, 4.0.0-rc1, dev-dev/building-menu, dev-master, 4.0.x-dev] but these are rejected
>   by your constraint.

The Silverstripe version is : 4.0.3

The composer.json is:

```
{
"name": "silverstripe/installer",
"type": "silverstripe-recipe",
"description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "silverstripe/recipe-plugin": "^1",
    "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "1.0.3@stable",
    "silverstripe-themes/simple": "~3.2.0",
    "undefinedoffset/sortablegridfield": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
},
"extra": {
    "project-files": [
        "assets/*",
        "mysite/_config/*",
        ".env.example",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "project-files-installed": [
        ".htaccess",
        "index.php",
        "install-frameworkmissing.html",
        "install.php",
        "mysite/.htaccess",
        "mysite/_config.php",
        "mysite/_config/mysite.yml",
        "mysite/code/Page.php",
        "mysite/code/PageController.php",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 600,
    "platform": {

    }
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

}

How do I fix this issue ? Is it due to the SS version I am using ?

Thanks,
Hemant Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your command works on my machine (Win10, Git Bash), you can try to wrap the version constraint incl. the caret `^` in double qoutes like:

```
composer require tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent:"^4"
```

This also works on my local dev setup and installs latest 4.0.0.-rc1

Comment: No it does not work for me either, I too use Windows 10 ? What is the version of Silverstripe you have installed ?

Comment: Ok I have installed Git Bash, and then I was able to install the module, dont know what difference it makes using Git Bash ? But anyway thanks for the hint :)

Comment: windows console is not bash, therefore there are subtle differences

Comment: by the way: if it solved your question feel free to "accept" the answer.